# How to segment the text part of a document image when the backgroud is quite similar as the paper?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am working on a OCR project and the document image needs unwarping operation. But I find that the color of the background is very similar as the paper.

[image: the sample image]

To deal with this issue, my solution is to find the text part and filled as a connected polygon. The code is as follows.

```
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np


#function to order points to proper rectangle
def order_points(pts):
    # initialzie a list of coordinates that will be ordered
    # such that the first entry in the list is the top-left,
    # the second entry is the top-right, the third is the
    # bottom-right, and the fourth is the bottom-left
    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype="float32")

    # the top-left point will have the smallest sum, whereas
    # the bottom-right point will have the largest sum
    s = pts.sum(axis=1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]

    # now, compute the difference between the points, the
    # top-right point will have the smallest difference,
    # whereas the bottom-left will have the largest difference
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis=1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]

    # return the ordered coordinates
    return rect


#function to transform image to four points
def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    # obtain a consistent order of the points and unpack them
    # individually
    rect = order_points(pts)

    # # multiply the rectangle by the original ratio
    # rect *= ratio

    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect

    # compute the width of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between bottom-right and bottom-left
    # x-coordiates or the top-right and top-left x-coordinates
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))

    # compute the height of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between the top-right and bottom-right
    # y-coordinates or the top-left and bottom-left y-coordinates
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))

    # now that we have the dimensions of the new image, construct
    # the set of destination points to obtain a "birds eye view",
    # (i.e. top-down view) of the image, again specifying points
    # in the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
    # order
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype="float32")

    # compute the perspective transform matrix and then apply it
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))

    # return the warped image
    return warped


#function to find two largest countours which ones are may be
#  full image and our rectangle edged object
def findLargestCountours(cntList, cntWidths):
    newCntList = []
    newCntWidths = []

    #finding 1st largest rectangle
    first_largest_cnt_pos = cntWidths.index(max(cntWidths))

    # adding it in new
    newCntList.append(cntList[first_largest_cnt_pos])
    newCntWidths.append(cntWidths[first_largest_cnt_pos])

    #removing it from old
    cntList.pop(first_largest_cnt_pos)
    cntWidths.pop(first_largest_cnt_pos)

    #finding second largest rectangle
    seccond_largest_cnt_pos = cntWidths.index(max(cntWidths))

    # adding it in new
    newCntList.append(cntList[seccond_largest_cnt_pos])
    newCntWidths.append(cntWidths[seccond_largest_cnt_pos])

    #removing it from old
    cntList.pop(seccond_largest_cnt_pos)
    cntWidths.pop(seccond_largest_cnt_pos)

    print('Old Screen Dimentions filtered', cntWidths)
    print('Screen Dimentions filtered', newCntWidths)
    return newCntList, newCntWidths


#driver function which identifieng 4 corners and doing four point transformation
def convert_object(image, screen_size = None, isDebug = False):

    image = imutils.resize(image,height=600)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)  # 11  //TODO 11 FRO OFFLINE MAY NEED TO TUNE TO 5 FOR ONLINE

    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    grad = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
    if isDebug : 
        cv2.imshow('grad', grad)
    _, bw = cv2.threshold(grad, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    if isDebug : 
            cv2.imshow('bw', bw)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (30, 50))
    connected = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    kernel=np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    connected=cv2.dilate(connected,kernel,iterations=3)
    # using RETR_EXTERNAL instead of RETR_CCOMP
    countours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    if isDebug : print('length of countours ', len(countours))
    imageCopy = image.copy()
    if isDebug : cv2.imshow('drawn countours', cv2.drawContours(imageCopy, countours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1))
    cnts = sorted(countours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
    hull = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)  
    for cnt in cnts:
        approx = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
        cv2.drawContours(hull, [approx], -1, (255, 0, 0), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    if isDebug :   cv2.imshow("hull", hull)

    
    grayhull = cv2.cvtColor(hull, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    countours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(grayhull.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    if isDebug : print('length of countours ', len(countours))

    imageCopy = image.copy()
    if isDebug : cv2.imshow('drawn countours', cv2.drawContours(imageCopy, countours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3))

    mask = np.zeros(bw.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    rgb = image.copy()

    for idx in range(len(countours)):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(countours[idx])
        mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 0
        cv2.drawContours(mask, countours, idx, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        r = float(cv2.countNonZero(mask[y:y+h, x:x+w])) / (w * h)
        if r > 0.45 and w > 8 and h > 8:
            cv2.rectangle(rgb, (x, y), (x+w-1, y+h-1), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    if isDebug :   cv2.imshow("rgb", rgb)
        
    # approximate the contour
    cnts = sorted(countours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
    screenCntList = []
    scrWidths = []
    for cnt in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)  # cnts[1] always rectangle O.o
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.05 * peri, True)
        screenCnt = approx
        print(len(approx))

        if (len(screenCnt) == 4):

            (X, Y, W, H) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            # print('X Y W H', (X, Y, W, H))
            screenCntList.append(screenCnt)
            scrWidths.append(W)
    print('Screens found :', len(screenCntList))
    print('Screen Dimentions', scrWidths)

    if len(screenCntList) > 1:
        screenCntList, scrWidths = findLargestCountours(screenCntList, scrWidths)
    print(screenCntList)

    if isDebug :   cv2.imshow(" Screen", cv2.drawContours(image.copy(), [screenCntList[0]], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3))

    pts = screenCntList[0].reshape(4, 2)
    print('Found bill rectagle at ', pts)
    rect = order_points(pts)
    print(rect)

    # apply the four point tranform to obtain a "birds eye view" of
    # the image
    warp = four_point_transform(image, pts)

    # show the original and warped images
    if(isDebug):
        cv2.imshow("Original", image)
        cv2.imshow("warp", warp)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    cv2.imwrite("result.png",warp.astype(np.uint8))
convert_object(cv2.imread('abc.jpg'), isDebug=True)
```

But because of the paragram indentation, the `approxPolyDP` can not find the boundary well.
[image: result of approxPolyDP]
Is there any effective solution for this case? thanks in advance.

Comment: what? your presented pictures don't contain "paper", they contain text and white background. why do you talk about a difference between "paper" and "background" when you present only ONE of these things?

Comment: Yes, as you know, the paper is captureed when it is on a white desk.

Comment: locate text lines. you want something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YW4K.png *then* take all the left ends and all the right ends of those lines https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaMwS.png, and do a RANSAC fit through each end (not least squares but something like median, ignoring outliers). that should give you the left and right bounds of the text block. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk4Fi.png -- for horizontal bounds, just take the topmost and bottommost text lines, calculate homography, and in the flattened space add some padding (can't do that easily in perspective-distorted space).

Comment: It is a good idea. Thanks a lot, Christoph.